# Swipe right should show the left sidebar on Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

As the title says, a right swipe in the main area should show the left sidebar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It currently does. You just need to have your finger on the very left side and drag out the menu. From the middle it won't work and I'm not sure it should either.

Comment: Exactly correct. The left sidebar is implemented exactly to [Google's standards](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) which state "swiping from the left edge of the screen".

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I noticed that when I saw the google standard "Menu" button above.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Oh, I thought it was "swiping right", but I see I was wrong